# Do I need transit visa for my layover in UK

Tags: visas, uk, transit

Me and my family live in Sweden. We are travelling from Gran Canaria to Copenhagen, with layover in Manchester to change flights.

My family members who I am travelling with have Swedish citizenship (Swedish passport). Myself on the other hand have Iranian passport, but I have permanent residence permit card issued in Sweden (see attached file). My question is: Do I need transit visa to UK, if I have this residence permit?

I have talked to our airline and it seems like we have to go through UK border control when we arrive in Manchester to change flights. I don’t know if this matters.

I have checked if I need visa in UK government website and it is written here that I need. However, it is also written here, there is possibility to transit without visa if:

•   you arrive and depart by air(yes, I will travel by planes)

•   have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive(yes, I have)

•   have the correct documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country) (yes, I have permanent residence permit in Sweden)

And also I must have at least one point from the list in website:

•   Have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland (yes, I have)

My question: Do I really need transit visa? [image]to UK?

Comment: That card is indeed a "common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country". See https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-11/handbook-annex_22_en.pdf page 88.

Comment: If you’re self-connecting in Manchester, be aware that a possible risk is you don’t make your connecting flight for some reason (late inbound flight, cancelled onward flight) which could result in you not being able to fulfil the second requirement you list in your question